# Angular ui-router not working. Do I need a server? Basic issues?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase

I am still pretty new to coding so here goes a simple question. I am having some problems with angular ui-router. I am using Angular with Firebase. I created an index.html with  to render my views. Then I assigned home.html and music.html in my states via app.config like so...

```
var app = angular.module('launchPage', ["ui.router","firebase"]);

app.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'FirstCtrl'
    })
  .state('year', {
  url: '/year/{year}',
  templateUrl: 'music.html',
  controller: 'FirstCtrl'
});

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

........

Now I was unsure why I couldn't get the templates to render. I thought maybe I needed a server so I installed node and http-server but as I made updates, they were not reflected after killing the server and restarting. I also just tried opening the index.html directly but that did not work either.

Here is my index.html as well

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Music App</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="launchPage">
    <div>     
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there some blatant point im missing besides not knowing if I need a server running? I feel like this should be a two second problem.

Comment: It should be `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')`

Comment: That actually fixed it!

Comment: Actually, not quite. It's almost like my http-server isn't picking up changes to my html. Any idea why?

Comment: Cmd+Shift+R for a hard refresh. Also, you can try to cache bust with a query string `/home?hello="world"`